# How do I show product short description in search result?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have WordPress, WooCommerce setup and when I try to search I am getting the product results with the product description, and I want to show the product's short description instead.

Can anyone please help me with which template file I should be editing in my child theme? I tried single.php and archive-product.php but can't find anything obvious.

Comment: Woocommerce > templates > content-product.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can make your custom code for doing for making it done by action hook. See the below code for full reference. This code is for showing extra design after product title in shop page. you should modify it according to your own.

```
    <?php
/*show shop product extra values*/
function show_shop_page_extra_data()
{
global $product;
$brand = get_the_terms($product->post->ID, 'pwb-brand');
$price = wc_get_product($product->post->ID);

if (!empty($product->post->post_content)) {
    echo '<h2 style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px;" >' . $brand[0]->name . '</h2>';
    echo '<p class="custom-product-price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">৳&nbsp;</span>' . $price->price . '</p>';
    echo '<p class="custom-product-description">' . $product->post->post_content . '</p>';

    global $product;
    global $post;
    if (get_post_type($post) === 'product' && !is_a($product, 'WC_Product')) {
        $product = wc_get_product(get_the_id()); // Get the WC_Product Object
    }

    $product_attributes = $product->get_attributes(); // Get the product attributes
    echo '<div class="circleDiv">';
    foreach ($product_attributes['pa_color']['options'] as $attribute) {
        $term = get_term($attribute); ?>

        <span class="dotCircle" style="    background-color: <?php echo $term->description; ?>;"></span>

        <?php
    }
    echo '</div>'; ?>

        <?php
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'show_shop_page_extra_data');
```